# How do I express this? "Did it (to) you?"

Tags: grammar

Suppose I encountered a unique product yesterday and I'm very impressed. I'm now meeting my friend after two days. She has also seen the product.

> Yeah! That product really stunned me. **_________________**?

Fill in the blank. I want to ask her whether or not she too got stunned.

My confusion -

> Did it you? (Considering that product *did* stun me). 
>   Did it to you? (Someone suggested this, though I'm not convinced).

Please mind it, I don't want to repeat the word *stunned*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way of saying this would not be to use the verb "to do."

> The opera really moved me. Did it you?

would be understandable, but it would sound extremely stilted; I would expect it to be said by a wealthy elderly woman wearing a lorgnette. Using "to you" is not idiomatic under any circumstances.

More likely, you would say something along the lines of:

> The opera really moved me. **How about you?**

or

> The opera really moved me. **What did you think?**

If you really want to get at the question of whether the person was "moved," or in your example "stunned," then you will need to repeat the word in question.

> The presentation really stunned me. Were you stunned, too?

Even here, it would be more natural to say something along the lines of:

> The presentation really stunned me. How about you--were you stunned, too?

If you really insist on asking about the specific element of the experience, but not repeating the word, you can do it, but it will sound a little clumsy:

> The opera really moved me. **Did it affect you that way, too?**

In the end, the closest idiomatic way to ask the question you want to ask is:

> How about you?

Comment: It does not sound stilted at all to me, it sounds idiomatic and colloquial -- although I may be in the demographic described (English, late middle-aged, middle-class). So I'm afraid I disagree with you that you wouldn't hear it.

Answer (score 0):

'Did it you' is correct. Though in conversation you'd probably never put it like that.

Comment: then how do you put it? without repeating 'stunned'?

Comment: I would say "What did you think?" - I wouldn't assume the other person would be stunned at all.

Comment: Well, I would probably put it like that. Perfectly adequately idiomatic English.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your question with "Did", you have to specify *what* may have happened; you cannot leave out the subsequent verb.  About the only exception to that is when you ask "Did (*pronoun*)?", and the only reason you're able to get away with that is when it's absolutely clear from context that you're talking about an action that someone is accused of performing in the previous sentence:

> "You cut me off!"
> "Did I?"

or

> "She's upset because she thinks I kissed her sister."
> "Did you?"

If the "Did"-question is longer than 2 words, you cannot leave out the action:

> "That scene really moved me.  Did it move you too?"
>
> "I was shocked and disturbed when I saw that.  Did you feel the same way?"

If you try to shorten it up, you get an ungrammatical utterance:

> "That scene really moved me.  <strike>Did it you?</strike>"

As noted in chapka's answer, "How about you?" or "What about you?" are good, idiomatic, short ways to ask if a person was similarly affected.

Comment: I disagree, as a native Englishman. It sounds normal, colloquial and idiomatic to my ears.

Comment: @PrimeMover perhaps I should mark this as AmE.